# Dynamically Adjust Width of Table View Embedded in Popover to Fit Cell Content

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipresentationcontroller

My landscape, iPad app has a table view controller presented as popover from a bar button item.

To fit the popover to the table view size, I do this on the table view controller's code:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.scrollEnabled = false
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    tableView.reloadData()   
    preferredContentSize = tableView.contentSize
}
```

This works fine for adjusting the popover's height to that of the table view (taking into account number of rows and height of each row).

**However,** if I set the label of one of the cells to a string that is too long, it will truncate (`...`), even though there is plenty of room on screen for the popover (and the table view) to grow further horizontally.

I could hard-code some big-enough width, like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    tableView.reloadData() 

    var size = tableView.contentSize
    size.width = 600  
    preferredContentSize = size 
}
```

...but I would prefer a more dynamic and elegant solution (e.g. minimum width that fits all cells' contents).

Comment: brother please add screenshot so i can understand more clearly

Comment: The `label` of the table view cell reads: "OneTwoThr..." instead of "OneTwoThreeFour.". The table view and popover could still grow horizontally to accommodate it, but they don't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use these for handle them dynamically

```
DynamicView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin .union(UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin .union(UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin))
```